# ZFS on LUKS not recognized at boot

Tags: zfs, systemd, luks, zfsonlinux, dmcrypt

I've got 6 physical drives in RAID-Z2, which I intend to one-by-one convert to dm-crypt devices.

My process was roughly:

1. `dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdf`
2. Create keyfile `/etc/crypttab.d/crypt-1.key`
3. `cryptsetup luksFormat /dev/sdf`
4. Append `crypt-1 <raw-disk-uuid> /etc/crypttab.d/crypt-1.key luks` to `/etc/crypttab`
5. `cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/sdf crypt-1`
6. `zfs replace my_pool <raw-disk-uuid> /dev/mapper/crypt-1`

Once the resilvering was finished (which worked fine), I rebooted the machine to verify the setup before continuing to other disks. What I found, however, was that ZFS labeled `crypt-1` as UNAVAIL.

`ls /dev/mapper` verified that dm-crypt activated the LUKS container correctly. Running `zpool online my_pool crypt-1` causes ZFS to begin resilvering but then completes and resumes healthy operation in a manner of seconds.

I'm guessing the dm-crypt device is simply not loaded when ZFS first tries to accesses `my_pool`? Is it a question of load-order or do I need to be using a different identifier for the LUKS device in `/etc/crypttab`? How do I ensure that ZFS sees these LUKS devices on reboot?

This is a `systemd` box (Arch) if that matters.

Thanks!

---

**EDIT 1:**

During cryptsetup creation, I used the SCSI identifiers (e.g. `/dev/sdf`) to initialize the device with LUKS. However, in `/etc/crypttab` I'm specifying the devices through the UUID of the underlying physical disk. Is the `cryptsetup` utility sensitive to how you identify targets? In other words, do I need to re-do my `cryptsetup` and pass it the disk UUID instead of the SCSI name?

---

**EDIT 2:**

I see the following `ls -alsvh /dev/disk/by-id`:

```
0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  10 Jul  8 08:18 dm-uuid-CRYPT-LUKS1-6bed03ceaafe4539a375536d11309ff0-locker-1 -> ../../dm-0
```

From what I know, if it's in `/dev/disk/by-id` it is - by definition? - not subject to change (even across reboots). I will replace the definition of the dm-crypt-name `locker-1` in my zpool with the id-name `/dev/disk/by-id/dm-uuid-CRYPT-LUKS1-6bed03ceaafe4539a375536d11309ff0-locker-1` and report back. Same drive, same LUKS container, just a different way of addressing it.

---

**EDIT 3:**

My proposal from edit #2 above did not work. I had to wipe the drive and re-`cryptsetup` the device because ZFS would not allow me to replace the device with itself. After resilvering was complete I rebooted and `zpool status` is `DEGRADED` and device `dm-uuid-CRYPT-LUKS1-71e12fa7dc034d919e800ba89aec3b17-locker-1` is `UNAVAIL`.

It's worth noting that `locker-1` **does** appear in `ls /dev/disk/by-id` as well as `lsblk`, so it is being loaded correctly. I can verify this by running:

```
zpool online inground dm-uuid-CRYPT-LUKS1-71e12fa7dc034d919e800ba89aec3b17-locker-1
```

Which exits cleanly, and brings the device back into the pool.

Perhaps this is due to the load order of different modules during boot? Maybe the activation of dm-crypt devices is done such that ZFS begins importing pools before the LUKS container is properly open?

Comment: Use UUIDs or WWNs whenever you can in ZFS.

Comment: Agreed, and I've been using UUIDs in all of my ZFS configurations - are `/dev/mapper` entries not considered WWNs? If not, how can I retrieve a UUID or WWN for the dm-crypt devices in `/dev/mapper`?

Comment: I've just updated step #6 - when I ran the command I fully qualified the path to `/dev/mapper/crypt-1` but neglected to reflect that in my example above.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to export your pool, then symlink the device nodes of call constituent devices into e.g. /dev/vdevs, and run

```
zpool import -d /dev/vdevs poolname
```

If the vdev is found this way, then you can make the symlinking occur before the zpool import in the bootprocess (either maybe via udev, or a script) as a workaround.